# Visualize Classes in Java Type Hierarchy, which implement different functions?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

How to easily visualize a Class in Java Type Hierarchy, which implement different functions. 
With multiple layers of inheritence finding the correct Class which implements a function gets complicated. Ho we have a feature in eclipse to support it ?

Comment: In eclipse, you can use ctrl+t to visualise the java type hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending what you really need - an UML diagram, an inheritance structure?

There are plenty of tools you can use, ranging from those that will create a documentation with UML diagrams for every class to plugins and some funny implementations. Take a look at those from this list:

- [UDoc](http://udoc.sourceforge.net/main/index.html) - dynamic visualization similar to UML diagrams.
- [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_ydoc.html) - doclet for JavaDoc that will output UML diagrams.
- [SCG](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/softwarecartography) - software cartography is an amazing visualization tool with Eclipse plugin.

But I guess what you really need, in case of Eclipse, is [Implementors Plugin](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/implementors/) with a possible addition of [Call Hierarchy Plugin](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/call-hierarchy/features.html). But it's just my guess...

Answer (score 0):

UML is the usual visualization tool.  I doubt that it'll help much here.

It's easy to do in IntelliJ: it shows a symbol in the left gutter that shows me all the classes that implement a given method if I click on it.